# What`s the best (in performance) way to transform nested data in MySQL to a nested data in PHP Arrays/Object?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

The most common first try is (pseudo-code):

```
posts = SELECT * FROM posts

for each (post in posts) {
    post[comments] = SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = {post[id]}
}
```

But is better to have JOINs, right? (or not? tell me) So:

```
posts = SELECT * FROM posts JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id
```

So the result will be something like:

```
post_id | post | comment_id | comment
===============================================
1       | foo  | 1          | nice foo
1       | foo  | 2          | dont like ur foo
2       | bar  | 3          | bar is better
```

How to convert to this?

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'post' => 'foo',
        'comments' => array(
            array('id' = 1, 'comment' => 'nice foo'),
            array('id' = 2, 'comment' => 'dont like ur foo'),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'post' => 'bar'
        'comments' => array(
            array('id' = 1, 'comment' => 'bar is better')
        )
    ),
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just loop over the result set and build the array appropriately... presumable post_id is a primary key and thus unique so you can use that as an array key and check to see if the post has been created and then either jsut add the comment data, or crate a post and then add the comment data.

For example in pseudo-php-code:

```
$posts = array();
while(false !== ($row = whatever_assoc_fetch_func($result))) {

   $id = $row['post_id'];
   $commentId = $row['comment_id'];

   if(!isset($posts[$id])) {
      $posts[$id] = array(
         'id' => $id,
         'post' => $row['post'],
         'comments' => array()
      );
   }

   $posts[$id]['comments'][$commentId] = array(
       'comment_id' => $commentId,
       'comment' => $row['comment']
   );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should most definitely use `JOIN`'s when possible along with explicitly selecting your columns. Example (not tested):

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.a AS tbl1_a,
  tbl1.b AS tbl1_b,
  tbl1.c AS tbl1_c,
  tbl2.a AS tbl2_a,
  tbl2.b AS tbl2_b,
  tbl2.c AS tbl2_c
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.parent_id = tbl1.id
```

There are many types of joins, all of which can be learned here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

[image]

Comment: OK. But the result will always be a plain table. What is the best way to transform that plain data into a nested architecture of arrays/objects?

Comment: Using a scripted solution, not on the database layer.

Comment: Yeah. That's the question. The better script to loop over the result and return the nested structure.